# Creating Project Cordova 3.5

Tags: cordova, terminal, upgrade, updates, tmp

I am trying to upgrade my Cordova version from 2.9 to 3.5 (not using CLI version). When I use Terminal to create it, the project does not have a CordovaLib as the instructions say. And there is an error saying Tmp: Permission Denied

does anyone have a fix for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project architecture between Cordova 2 and 3 changed.  The base cordova create command only creates the "raw" project directory structure.  It sounds like your utilizing Eclipse/Android since you mention the CordovaLib as a project.  Have you tried adding the android platform to the project from inside the root project directory: cordova platform add android ?  This should create an Eclipse project under the platforms/android sub directory.  You should be able to open this from inside of Eclipse (Import existing Android Project) and complete configuring your Android project.  Then you can move your 2.9 code into the www directory, execute a prepare command: cordova platform prepare android , and find your Cordova Eclipse project ready to finish configuring.  You'll need to insure that you've setup your Eclipse environment properly with the Android SDK.